# Same image used thrice but only appears 2 times via CSS

Tags: html, css, image, url

would appreciate any insight to my issue. I'm trying to use the same image for placeholder purposes and I need it three times but when I link it via css it only appears twice correctly and I have no idea why it won't appear the third time.

Here is the HTML snip:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <h5>Get in Touch?</h5>
                <h3><a href="#facebook" class="footer_facebook">Add Me</a></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <h5>Hire for a Project?</h5>
                <h3><a href="#gmail" class="footer_mail">E-Mail Me</a></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <h5>Need Information?</h5>
                <h3><a href="#skype" class="footer_skype">Skype Me</a></h3>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS snip:

```
a.footer_facebook {
background: url(../img/icon_email.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; 
}
a.footer_mail {
background: url(../img/icon_email.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; 
}
a.footer_skype {
background: url(../img/icon_email.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent; 
}
```

As you can see. The same image is being used. It works and appears just fine for the mail and skype part but doesn't appear for the facebook part and I have no idea why. If I change the HTML code class from 'footer_facebook' to 'footer_mail/skype' the icon appears. The code appears in order to me and I validated my html with no errors. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the problematic element with your browser's developer tools? I suspect there are other CSS rules at play here that you haven't provided in your code snippets.

Comment: This is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fjr7dkm/, it looks fine, your problem is outside the posted code in question.

Comment: @Andre Dion: When I click on where the logo should appear, nothing appears in the styles tab on the right showing that there is a background image linked to that area. But when I click on the other two areas for skype and email, an attribute pops up saying that there is a background and the url points to the correct logo. I will upload an image to the OP. Edit: Short on 4 rep to upload images.

Thanks for the reply Moshtaf, tried that too before posting here and it worked fine but clueless as to why its not working in my file. Been at it a while and just stuck here.

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot from my dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6lqq1ywnjb5xue/Screenshot.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Never mind guys. I just deleted those bits and retyped it out and somehow it worked. Thanks anyways!